VBA Macro Not Triggering Automatically on Cell Change
I'm having trouble getting a macro to trigger automatically when I change the value in a cell. The macro is supposed to update currency values across multiple ranges, but it only works if I manually run it after changing the value.
Here’s the code I’m using:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Check if U1 is changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("U1")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Run the UpdateValues procedure when U1 changes
        UpdateValues
    End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currencySheet As Worksheet
    Dim u1Value As Integer
    Dim newConversionRate As Double
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim actualConversionRate As Double
    Dim rangesToConvert As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Set references to the sheets
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("August")   ' Your main sheet
    Set currencySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Currencies")   ' Currency rates sheet

    ' Get the value of U1 (the selected conversion option)
    u1Value = ws.Range("U1").Value
    
    ' Ensure U1 value is valid
    If u1Value < 1 Or u1Value > 5 Then
        Exit Sub ' Exit without doing anything if U1 is not valid
    End If

    ' Get the new conversion rate from the Currencies sheet
    newConversionRate = currencySheet.Cells(u1Value + 1, 2).Value ' Currencies!B2 to B6 based on U1 value
    
    ' Get the previous conversion rate from A1
    actualConversionRate = ws.Range("A1").Value

    ' If the previous conversion rate is 0, set it to 1 to avoid division by zero
    If actualConversionRate = 0 Then
        actualConversionRate = 1
    End If

    ' Define the ranges to convert
    rangesToConvert = Array("B3:AG22", "B24:AG39", "B41:AG48", "B50:AG56", "B58:AG65", "B67:AG77", "B79:AG86", _
                            "B88:AG101", "B103:AG114", "B116:AG121", "B123:AG131", "B133:AG138", "B140:AG141")

    ' Loop through each defined range and update the values
    For i = LBound(rangesToConvert) To UBound(rangesToConvert)
        Set rangeToConvert = ws.Range(rangesToConvert(i))

        For Each cell In rangeToConvert
            ' Check if the cell value is numeric and not empty
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                ' Divide by the previous conversion rate and then multiply by the new conversion rate
                cell.Value = (cell.Value / actualConversionRate) * newConversionRate
            End If
        Next cell
    Next i

    ' Update the previous conversion rate in A1 to the new conversion rate
    ws.Range("A1").Value = newConversionRate
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub

The goal is for the macro to detect when U1 changes and update the values immediately, but for some reason, it doesn’t fire.
Has anyone run into this issue before? Any ideas on how to make it update automatically when U1 changes? Would appreciate any insights!
I've tried different solutions, but none seem to work. I'm likely missing something, maybe in my settings.

Is this in a normal module or the sheet's module?

@Warcupine Me.Range wouldn't compile in a normal module.

Ahh true, didn't see that

Does U1 contain a formula?

Is .EnableEvents Off or On? You can check that by typing ?application.EnableEvents in the immediate window.

@BigBen no its a value atached, to diffrent option buttons, going from 1 to 5

@SiddharthRout yes, its true

Is it works if the value is not currency?

Worksheet_Change doesn't fire when a cell linked to option buttons changes.

As BigBen said change events are not generated by linked-cell changes. You could remove the link and assign them to a macro, for example
Sub OptionButton()
    Dim n As Long
    Select Case Application.Caller
       Case "Option Button 1": n = 1
       Case "Option Button 2": n = 2
       Case "Option Button 3": n = 3
    End Select
    Me.Range("U1") = n
End Sub

Also, you don't need the Worksheet_Change Sub if you add a call to UpdateValues in this Sub.

A Worksheet Change: Write to Sheet When Cell Changes

Not tested! It compiles.

Sheet Module, e.g. August
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    UpdateValues Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1 (or the same sheet module)
Sub UpdateValues(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Implement an error-handling routine to ensure events get enabled
    ' if an error occurs.
    Dim MsgString As String
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
        
    ' Define constants.
    Const TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "U1"
    Const TARGET_RATE_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME As String = "Currencies"
    Const LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const MIN_VALUE As Long = 1
    Const MAX_VALUE As Long = 5
    Dim RANGES_TO_CONVERT() As Variant: RANGES_TO_CONVERT = Array( _
        "B3:AG22", "B24:AG39", "B41:AG48", "B50:AG56", "B58:AG65", _
        "B67:AG77", "B79:AG86", "B88:AG101", "B103:AG114", "B116:AG121", _
        "B123:AG131", "B133:AG138", "B140:AG141")
    
    ' Reference the target sheet and cell.
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = tws.Range(TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Exit if the target cell was not changed.
    If Intersect(tcell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Get the value of cell 'U1' (the selected conversion option).
    Dim Value As Variant: Value = tcell.Value

    ' Exit if the value is 'invalid'.      
    If Not IsNumeric(Value) Then Exit Sub ' not numeric
    If Value < MIN_VALUE Or Value > MAX_VALUE Then Exit Sub ' out of bounds
    If Int(Value) <> Value Then Exit Sub ' not an integer

    ' Reference the lookup sheet.
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = tws.Parent.Sheets(LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Get the new conversion rate from the Currencies sheet
    ' of cell 'B2' To 'B6' (1 To 5) based on target cell.
    Dim NewRate As Double: NewRate = lws.Cells(Value + 1, LOOKUP_COLUMN).Value

    ' Get the previous conversion rate from cell 'A1'.
    Dim OldRate As Double: OldRate = tws.Range(TARGET_RATE_CELL_ADDRESS).Value
    ' If the previous conversion rate is 0, set it to 1
    ' to avoid division by zero.
    If OldRate = 0 Then OldRate = 1
        
    ' Always disable events before writing to the target sheet
    ' to prevent retriggering this event (and triggering any other events)!
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim rg As Range, cell As Range, i As Long

    ' Loop through each defined range and update the values.
    For i = LBound(RANGES_TO_CONVERT) To UBound(RANGES_TO_CONVERT)
        Set rg = tws.Range(RANGES_TO_CONVERT(i))
        ' Loop through each cell of current range.
        For Each cell In rg.Cells
            Value = cell.Value ' read
            ' Check if the cell contains a number.
            If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then ' is number
                ' Divide by the old conversion rate
                ' and multiply by the new conversion rate.
                cell.Value = (Value / OldRate) * NewRate
            End If
        Next cell
    Next i

    ' Update the previous to the new conversion rate in cell 'A1'.
    tws.Range(TARGET_RATE_CELL_ADDRESS).Value = NewRate

ProcExit:
    ' Prevent endless loop if error in continuation.
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' enable events ('at all cost!')
        If Len(MsgString) > 0 Then MsgBox MsgString, vbCritical
    On Error GoTo 0 ' enable error trapping (default)
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgString = "Runtime error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit ' redirect error-handling routine
End Sub


Do While Range("A22") = "Macro L: Running"
I have a load of code after this that stops if you select cell A22 (on a Freeze Pane) and press DEL. Your code before:
Loop
